# Add image not providing north arrow directory in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm still using QGIS Brighton to finish a map in Composer and would like to add a north arrow to it.  In previous versions I added the arrow as an image, but when I click on 'add image' and click on the map I only see a cross where the cursor would be. The command history doesn't change and no directory appears from which I can choose and customise an image.

How do I access the image directory?

Answer (score 4):

When you choose "add image" you have to drag the cursor and you will get something like pic.1. Then, to the right side there is search directories you click on it and waiting to open an then you can choose your symbol pic.2.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I dragged the cursor and it worked as before. Getting feeble in my old age.  Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: If this solved you problem don't forget to click the green tick to Accept it.